# Plotting regression lines on the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression

Question here

[image]

Here, I am trying to plot multiple graphs on one plot. I can do the plots separately but how do I combine linear regression plots?

This is what I have tried till now -

```
qclm1<-lm(C~Y, data = qc)
summary(qclm1)
plot(Y, C)
abline(qclm1)

ggplot(data=data.frame( y=c(60,45,75,80,65,95,100,85,115),c=c(46,31,61,58,43,73,70,55,85) ), aes(x=y,y=c)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 10, slope = 0.6, col = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)

qclm2<-lm(C~I,data=qc)
plot(I, C)
abline(qclm2)
```

I want to combine all lines to one graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer ggplot2, try

```
data <- data.frame(C = rep(c(46,31,61,58,43,73,70,55,85), 2), 
                   type = rep(c('Y', 'I'), each = 9), 
                   value = c(60,45,75,80,65,95,100,85,115, 14, 14, 14, 22, 22, 22, 30, 30, 30))


ggplot(data, aes(value, C, col = type)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```